# Extrusion gone wrong?

Tags: modeling

I'm practicing following the classic donut exercise by BlenderGuru and tried to add some drops to my donut, but as soon as I did it this happens: [image: is that normal?]

I'm doing it in Edit mode, but the extrusion is showed in object mode? Is that right or I did something wrong?

As you can see, I'm a newbie in modeling ;))

Answer (score 0):

I've found it, it was really simple. I simply could have used the "Hidden wire" option.
[image]